# How to cast string input into "where in"

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, csv, thingworx

I have a Thingworx Service (SQL Query) in my Database Thing, eg. `GetCookiesByIds`

I have a parameter `ids` (STRING) with value `1,2,3`

I would like to make a query:

```
SELECT * FROM Cookies WHERE id IN ([[ids]])`
```

But I have an exception.

How to cast my parameter ids into the valid format?

Answer (score 1):

A)

`SELECT * FROM cookies WHERE id = any([[ids]]::int[])`

The value of `ids` must be like: `{1,2,3}`

---

B)

```
SELECT * FROM cookies WHERE id = any(
    CONCAT( '{', [[ids]], '}' ) ::int[]
)
```

The value of `ids` must be like: `1,2,3`

Answer (score 0):

A simple an portable option is:

```
select *
from cookies
where ',' || $1 || ',' like '%,' || id || ',%'
```

... where `$1` represents the CSV string that is the parameter to your query.

In Postgres, we can also use arrays:

```
select *
from cookies
where id = any(string_to_array($1, ','))
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax if you want to do that is like this

```
SELECT * FROM Cookies WHERE id IN (<<ids>>)
```

The Thingworx service will concatenate your input parameter in the query if you use `<<>>` and define it as actual parameters if you use `[[]]`

Answer (score 0):

Add some more details to Tom V's correct answer...

### CONTEXT

Surrounding the input parameter with double square brackets `[[IDs]]` is parameter substitution, which treats the input as a parameter **ONLY**. In order to pass a string variable in the input parameter, you must use the double angle brackets `<<IDs>>` which allows for string substitution.

> But be **WARNED**, string substitution can expose your database to SQL injection so be sure to sanitize the input and secure the services using string substitution.

### EXAMPLE

*Input Parameter:*
IDs (STRING)

 [the value can have a space but **MUST** be comma separated to return multiple values]

> IDs = 26,504

*Output Parameter:*
result (Infotable) 
 [in my example an Infotable is returned, but the output can be any data type]

*Query:*

```sql
SELECT * FROM Cookies WHERE id IN (<<IDs>>);
```

(Referenced article can be found [here](https://community.ptc.com/t5/ThingWorx-Developers/Problems-with-the-input-parameter-in-the-SQL-query-service/td-p/618832))

[image shows id casting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1cs9.png)